# C++ to calculate which point on a triangle is closest to another point

Tags: c++, 3d, linear-algebra, algebra

`point1`, `point2`, `point3` and `object` are instances of a custom `Vec3` class. Basically, they have **X**, **Y**, and **Z** coordinates.

The goal with this snippet is to consider the three points of a triangle, as well as the object position, and return the **closest point on the triangle** to the object.

Here are some of the referenced functions:

```
float dotProduct(const Vec3 &a, const Vec3 &b)
{
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z;
}

Vec3 crossProduct(const Vec3 &a, const Vec3 &b)
{
    return {a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y, a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z, a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x};
}

Vec3 normalize(const Vec3 &v)
{
    float length = std::sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y + v.z * v.z);
    return {v.x / length, v.y / length, v.z / length};
}
```

Here's the main snippet:

```
// Getting the normal vector of the triangle...
Vec3 edge1 = {point2.x - point1.x, point2.y - point1.y, point2.z - point1.z};
Vec3 edge2 = {point3.x - point1.x, point3.y - point1.y, point3.z - point1.z};
Vec3 normal = normalize(crossProduct(edge1, edge2));

// Calculate the vector from any point on the triangle to the object's position...
Vec3 playerToVertex1 = {object.x - point1.x, object.y - point1.y, object.z - point1.z};
float distance = dotProduct(playerToVertex1, normal);

Vec3 projectedPoint = {
    object.x - distance * normal.x,
    object.y - distance * normal.y,
    object.z - distance * normal.z
};
```

What I'm getting is this weird phenomenon where it will occasionally return points that seem to be in-line with the X and Z axis, but not the Y axis - leading the "projected" Vec3 to follow along the corners of the triangle, but hover way above them. It's super weird.

It's for a 3D game I'm developing for older hardware. In short, I can "walk" on top of cubes with my player character. I'm using this logic to parse through each triangle in the cube. *However*, when I try to walk *off* the cube, my logging shows that it's acting as if there is an invisible wall on all sides.

Anything obvious pop out to any of y'all?

Comment: Why the usage of `float` when `double` is more precise?

Comment: Can you show data for some of the input (the vertices of the triangle, and the other point) where it appears something is going wrong?   Hard to help without that.  My *guess* is that some of the vectors being calculated have significantly different lengths (e.g.  normalising a relatively small vector [dividing by its length] and then multiplying by length of a relatively large vector tends to amplify artefacts due to limited floating point precision).    Incidentally, the dot product of a vector with itself is its length squared.

Comment: Your projected point is the projection onto the PLANE of the triangle.  Such a projection need not even be inside or on the triangle. If the triangle is oriented obliquely in 3d space then a projection outside of the triangle may well look as if it is in free space.

Comment: If vec3 doesn't provide the full interface of a mathematical vector, I'd define a class with full set of operations: `a + b`, `a - b`, `dot(a,b)` `cross(a,b)`, `a+=b`, `a-=b`, `a.cross(b)`, `-a`, `+a`, `abs(a)`, `unit(a)`, `a.project(b)`. That would simplify reading the rest of my code and prevent repeating a lot of segments.